# Decidable? If a Turing Machine M, on input w, will M ever move its read/write head to the left?

Tags: turing-machines

1. If a Turing Machine M, on input w, will M ever move its read/write head to the left?
2. Determine if this violates Rice's Theorem.

**1.**
I think the answer for Q1 is decidable because we can make a Turing Machine that decides the problem as follows:

> Step 1: If M halts on w and it never moved left, reject it.
>
> Step 2: If M ever moves left, halt and accept.
>
> Step 3: If M loops forever (some configuration repeats) then reject it
>
> Step 4: Otherwise, reject (M moves right, eventually encounters a
> blank symbol, and moves right forever, which means that M will never
> move left. So, reject it.)

**2.**
We proved that for some language L L(M) is decidable. So, we can say that L(M) is Turing-recognizable. The property 'L(M) is Turing-recognizable' is trivial because there does not exist a Turing-recognizable L2 such that L2 does not belong to L. Thus, our problem is decidable with the following decider:

> "Step 2: If M ever moves left, halt and accept."

, and this does not violate Rice's Theorem.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that your logic doesn't make sense, since you can't implement Step 1. In order to implement it, you'll have to run $M$ and see if it every halts, but this is impossible, since it's the halting problem.

Nevertheless, the problem is decidable. The details of this argument depend on the exact Turing machine model, but in order to illustrate the basic idea, it suffices to consider the simplest possible model, in which there is only one head, and at each step, it has to move (either one step to the left, or one step to the right). We simulate $M$ for $|w|$ steps. Either it has moved to the left (in which case we know the answer), or otherwise, it has gone past the input.

In the latter case, suppose that the Turing machine is at some state $q$ after $|w|$ steps. Let's say that a state is *bad* if when $M$ reaches it, if the input under the head is blank, then it moves left. Construct a directed graph in which there is an arrow from $q$ to $p$ if $M$ transitions from $q$ to $p$ when the input under the head is blank. There are three cases:

- The path starting at $q$ reaches a bad state. In this case the head of $M$ will eventually move left.
- The path starting at $q$ reaches a halting state or closes a cycle, in both cases not going through a bad state. In this case the head of $M$ will never move left.

This shows how to decide whether $M$ every moves left upon reading $w$.

---

This might seem to contradict Rice's theorem, but it doesn't. The reason is not what you state — the problem is not trivial: there are pairs $(M,w)$ for which $M$ does move left when running on $w$, and there are other pairs when this doesn't happen. Rather, the property of never moving left is a *syntactic* property rather than a *semantic* property: it depends on the Turing machine $M$ instead of on its language $L(M)$.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!

Comment: Case 1: If M has moved to the left during its computation then we accept it. 
Case 2: If M has gone past the input, we should check what content is under the head at the end of its computation.
Case 2-1: If the input under the head is blank, the head of M will eventually move left. So, we accept it.
Case 2-2: If the input under the head reaches a halting state or closes a cycle, the head of M will never move left. So, we reject it.

Comment: Am I understanding your logic correctly?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I think my answer is verbose enough. I'll let you work it out.

Comment: In every situation, if the input under the head is blank, then will it move left? Isn't the machine supposed to move to the right if it encounters a blank symbol?

Comment: The machine does what you tell it to do.

Comment: "Let's say that a state is bad if when M reaches it" What do you mean by "it' here? Does your logic mean that if the machine reaches a bad state, then the input under the head is always blank, so it moves left?

Comment: Right, a state is bad if it will cause the machine to move left.

Comment: So, if the machine encounters a bad state after |w| steps, then it moves to the left from q to p, right?

Comment: By definition, if the machine reaches a bad state when there’s a blank under its head, then it moves left.

Comment: I see. If the machine ends at a halting state or closes a cycle after |w| steps (it has gone past the input), then the head of M will never move to the left by your logic, so we reject it, right? Thus, we can conclude that its problem is decidable.

Comment: That’s the basic idea.

Comment: The reason the problem does not violate Rice's Theorem is that it is not about a semantic property related to the program's behavior but about a syntactic property?

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer. This is explained very briefly on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt, precise answer! It hasn't been much time since I started using StackExchange, so you might have probably found it tough responding to me; Sorry about that.. Your answer is of big help!